# C++ Initialize abstract base class protected member for all derived classes

Tags: c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to initialize abstract base class' protected member for all derived objects without writing the same initializer list in all derived class constructors? So that it acts like a static member for all derived objects. What I want is something like this (except it doesn't work) Read it like a pseudo code:

A.h

```
class A {
public:
    A(string fn);
    virtual ~A();
    virtual void open_file() = 0;
protected:
    string fileName;
};
```

A.cpp

```
A::A(string fn) : fileName {fn} {} //Initializer list is written only once here
A::~A() {}
```

B.h

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    void open_file() const override;
};
```

B.cpp

```
B::B() {} //No initializer list for A::fileName here
void B::open_file() const {
    ifstream SomeFile(fileName); //Use base class' protected member
    ..... //Do some stuff with open file
}
```

And imagine there's also a `C` derived class without an initializer list for `A` here that has a different overriden `open_file` function..

main.cpp

```
string fname = {"foo.txt"};
A* APtr = new B(fname); //This initializes A's fileName for all derived objects as "foo.txt"
Aptr->open_file(); //B opens foo.txt
fname = "bar.txt";
A* A2Ptr = new C(fname); //Now fileName that both B and C consume is changed to "bar.txt"
A2Ptr->open_file(); //C opens bar.txt
APtr->open_file(); //B now opens bar.txt
```

Comment: 1. There's not a single `protected` member in the code you're showing. 2. It's not clear what you want to achieve. You're passing an argument in `new B`, but `B`'s constructor doesn't have a parameter. Can you clarify what exactly you're after? Do you want all `B`s to have the same value of `fileName`? If so, is this value known at compile time?

Comment: The example code I gave is like a pseudo code, I know it doesn't work. I want all `fileName` data that derived class objects use to be changed by every instantiation of a derived class, regardless of they are type `B` or `C`.

Comment: I still can't quite grasp your goal. Can you perhaps explain why making `fileName` a static protected member of `A` is not what you want?

Comment: Yes perhaps that's what I want, but how can I make it so that I only write one initializer list for `fileName` that governs all derived objects. As in the example imaginary code above, when I instantiate an `A*` to `B` with `fileName` sent to constructor, the global `fileName` will be changed for other instances of `B` or for a `C` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You deklared the constructor from B: `B();` but you try to use it `A* APtr = new B(fname);` So the compiler can't find any matching constructor.
2. > initialize abstract base class' protected member for all derived objects without writing the same initializer list in all derived class

   Why not?

A.hpp

```
class A
    {
    public:
       A( string fn = "") : fileName(fn){} // you can give an default path if prefered.
    };
```

B.hpp

```
class B : public A
{
public:
   B( string fn = "") : A( fn )  {} //c++11 feature: call base constructor.
}
```

3. Other possible solutions were:

   - global variable (dirty and unsafe! - Please don't do it.)
   - static variable in A. But you can only open one file the same time.
   - give A setter and getter for fileName. And use it that way:

main.cpp

```
B* b = new B();
b->setFileName("foo.txt");
b->openFile();
```

Comment: This option: "static variable in A. But you can only open one file the same time." I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: Also if I use a setter-getter will same `fileName` be available to all derived objects?

Comment: You have to decide what you want. - If you want the same variable for all your derived objects. You can only open 1 file. 
If i look in your main.cpp example, you created to object from b and c. Thats not such easy as you want.
2. No. Just one Object. 

But I don't now what you realy want to archiev. Describe the behaviour you want as precisly as possible.